# shell script to pass values properties file in java

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a properties file that looks like this:

```
mysql.username=USERNAME
mysql.pass=PASS
```

I need to change `USERNAME` and `PASS` with variable values passed to shell script. I cannot use `sed` since that will work fine the first time to replace USERNAME and PASS with "values" but once they are replaced, sed will not find the variable names in the file the second time the script runs and thus an issue.

How can this be handled?

Comment: You can use sed, don't search for `mysql.username=USERNAME` but rather for `mysql.username=` which will still be there after the replacement has been done. `sed "s/mysql.username=.*/mysql.username=$replacement/"`. Make sure the replacement value can't contain the delimiter you use in the sed command though or that'll break.

Comment: If you mean that you should be able to perform the replacement without knowing the `mysql.username=` part then it's not a `sed` problem either, you're just asking for the impossible; either keep the original file with the `USERNAME` and other placeholders and regenerate the file from this each time, or use another way to know what to replace as in my above comment

Comment: mysql.username is going to be there. I was talking about the placeholder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to achieve your goal is to always execute the substitutions on the untouched template file rather than trying to work on the previous version of the resulting file :

```
# produce a first version of the file.properties 
sed -e 's/USERNAME/user1/' -e 's/PASS/pass1/' file.properties.template > file.properties

# succesfully produce a second version of the file.properties
sed -e 's/USERNAME/user2/' -e 's/PASS/pass2/' file.properties.template > file.properties
```

Another alternative would be to change the input (or code?) of your script so that you would base your search&replace operation not on placeholder values but rather on the properties names :

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

target=$1
shift

while key=$1 && value=$2 && shift 2; do
    sed -i "s/^$key=.*/$key=$value/" $target
done

$ cat test.props
mysql.hostname=HOSTNAME
mysql.username=USERNAME
mysql.pass=PASS

$ ./test.sh test.props mysql.username sa mysql.pass clearTextPasswordsAreTerrible

$ cat test.props
mysql.hostname=HOSTNAME
mysql.username=sa
mysql.pass=clearTextPasswordsAreTerrible

$ ./test.sh test.props mysql.username secondTry mysql.pass successfullyModified

$ cat test.props
mysql.hostname=HOSTNAME
mysql.username=secondTry
mysql.pass=successfullyModified
```